How to Limit a Select List Filter to Search Based on Exact Matches Instead of Substrings
I am working on a project where I have a select list with a filter functionality. Currently, the filter searches for substrings within the options, but I would like to modify it so that it only searches for exact matches based on the selected data.
For example, if the select list of column index 2 contains the options "New" , I saw rows with "New" and some rows with "NRND (Not Recommended for New Design)" , the filter should not return any results of "NRND (Not Recommended for New Design)" because is not an exact match for "New", it was a substring of "New".
columns = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
table.columns([38]).every(function (i) {     
  var column = this;
  $(column.header()).append("");
  var select = $('<select style="max-width:80px"><option value="">--</option</select>')
    .appendTo($(column.header()))
    .on('change', function ({
       filter_values[column.index()] =$(this).val();
       table.search(filter_values.toString() ? '' + filter_values.toString() + '' : '', true, false).draw();
    });
    select.append('<option value="0">0.X</option>');
    select.append('<option value="1">1.X</option>');
    select.append('<option value="2">2.X</option>');
    select.append('<option value="3">3.X</option>');
});

$(column.header()).append("<br>");
var select = $('<select style="max-width:80px"><option value="">--</option></select>')
  .appendTo($(column.header()))
  .on('change', function () {
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    filter_values[column.index()] = selectedValue;

    // Use the search method to filter and display the data
    table.search(filter_values.toString() ? '' + filter_values.toString() + '' : '', true, false).draw();
  });

  // Populate the select options
  columns[column.index()].forEach(function (d, j) {
    select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
  }); 
});
table.columns([2, 3, 4, 9, 14, 23, 25]).every(function (i) {
    var column = this;

    // Append a line break and a select dropdown to each column header
    $(column.header()).append("<br>");
    var select = $('<select style="max-width:80px"><option value="">--</option></select>')
        .appendTo($(column.header()))
        .on('change', function () {
            var selectedValue = $(this).val();
            filter_values[column.index()] = selectedValue;

            // Use the search method to filter and display the data
            table.search(filter_values.toString() ? '' + filter_values.toString() + '' : '', true, false).draw();
        });


Regex is not functional

Please make that an MRE. As it is it's hard to understand what your code does and why it is written like it is - for example: What is filter_values? Why do you create two <select> elements? Do you use a ready-made datatable like this one or have you implemented it yourself (I'd guess the former, but don't know for sure)? Where's the regular expression that's "not functional"?

plus the code as is has syntax errors.. the function passed as the change event handler in the first loop is missing a closing ) in the arguments and there's an extra closing }); not required in the end. The data json is not provided, the filter_values was not provided, the html with a sample table was not provided. The question focus is on how to filter rows of a table showing only exact matches but the whole picture adds lots of noise making hard to discern the actual problem. Please put some effort doing something addressing exactly the issue in a reproducible way

filter_values contains the selected data from each column , I added the  element because it was a filter of a select list on every column (38) , the user will choose a colum to be filtred according to the selected list data , I did a wrong the code is missed a part of the selected list filters

@DiegoD you can review the total code now

I have tried this one with regex "       table.search(filter_values.toString() ? '^' + filter_values.toString() + '$' : '', true, false).draw();
});"

Actually, the code is functional as desired, but in some columns, it returns substrings. For example, if I filter the column from the selected list to 'Recommended', I see rows with 'not Recommended
